# (approximate) probability that all items in a multiset that is drawn with replacement have multiplicity $\geq k$.

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, birthday

This problem seems to be the following variation of the birthday problem: what is the probability that in a group of $p$ people nobody has a birthday that $<k$ people in the group have.

I'm also interested in the opposite problem, where nobody has a birthday that $\geq k$ people in the group have.

I think the exact probability can be calculated using the inclusion-exclusion principle, but does a simpler approach (I mean an expression that is easier to compute) or decent approximation exist here?

Comment: A decent approximation, in what ranges of $p$ and $k$?

Comment: I won't speak for OP, but I think approximations are best when $p \ll 365 k$. We might also want $k$ to be small compared to $365$, but it may still be possible to have nice approximation when that isn't the case.

Comment: Since this problem doesn't look like a very esoteric or strange one, I mainly just thought: maybe somebody recognizes this problem right away and knows of a well known approximation. I do not have very strict requirements for how good the approximation should be.